# What files does PHP require to run?

Tags: php, dll, libraries

Im having a new concept im trying out and it would require me to strip out all none required libraries within a typical PHP Install.

Within the main PHP folder we have a set of Dll files that i can't seem to figure out what there used for and im seeking some help.

the PHP installation that im basing my project is **PHP 5.3.5 Win32 x86** which has the following set of files I need to figure out what they are used for.

```
05/01/2011  20:36        11,361,792 icudt38.dll
05/01/2011  20:36         1,140,224 icuin38.dll
05/01/2011  20:36            41,472 icuio38.dll
05/01/2011  20:36           187,904 icule38.dll
05/01/2011  20:36            42,496 iculx38.dll
05/01/2011  20:36            50,176 icutest.dll
05/01/2011  20:36            99,840 icutu38.dll
05/01/2011  20:36         1,093,120 icuuc38.dll
05/01/2011  20:36         1,019,392 libeay32.dll
05/01/2011  20:36            43,008 libenchant.dll
05/01/2011  20:36            44,544 libenchant_ispell.dll
05/01/2011  20:36           293,888 libenchant_myspell.dll
05/01/2011  20:36            97,792 libpq.dll
05/01/2011  20:36            68,608 libsasl.dll
05/01/2011  20:36           805,200 php5embed.lib
05/01/2011  20:36           209,408 ssleay32.dll
```

ive already isolated several files that I know are required such as `php5.dll`, can anyone shed some light on what these are so I can choose weather I should include them within my project.

Regards

Comment: A bit tenuous this one. (Is this programming or sys admin?) Irrespective, a quick Google search for each of the above .dll files should tell you the relevant module/extension it provides support for.

Comment: i have tried but failed to find an exact answer for what there used for within the php distribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a list of the various extensions within the "[Installation of extensions on Windows](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php)" section of the PHP manual that provides some additional clues, but here's what I believe each of these DLLs are for:

- **Unicode** - icudt38.dll, icuin38.dll, icuio38.dll, icule38.dll, iculx38.dll, icutest.dll, icutu38.dll, icuuc38.dll
- **OpenSSL** - libeay32.dll, ssleay32.dll
- **Spell checking abstraction layer** - libenchant.dll, libenchant_ispell.dll, libenchant_myspell.dll
- **PostgreSQL** - libpq.dll
- **Cyrus SASL (LDAP, etc.)** - libsasl.dll
- **For use when embedding PHP5** - php5embed.lib

Comment: Thankyou so much, where would the Spell Checking be used ?

Comment: @RobertPitt These are presumably for the [Enchant spelling library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.enchant.php) and [Pspell](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pspell.php) extensions.